# Jquery $('#id').find('option').size() vs $('#id option').size() regarding "Maximum call stack size" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, callstack

I have a large dataset (100,000+), and there's a drop down select that is populated with options for each individual item. i.e.

```
<select id="list" multiple>
    <option val="0">item A</option>
      ...
    <option val="123456">item ZZZZZZ</option>
</select>
```

When trying to get the count for this list, the previously implemented line was
`this.find('option').size()` and would error with a maximum call stack size.
[image: Console Error 1]

[image: Console Error 2]

*The Solution*

I saw a variety of people saying the solution came down to checking for recursion. But I have not seen any issue with that while looking through the console. And running them in console I was hoping to avoid any issue with that altogether.

I DID find that using `$('#' + id + ' option').size()`
was able to work without throwing the error.
[image: Console Success]

*TESTING SIDE NOTE*

I ran these two lines in a benchmark for js created by user Ghetolay at https://jsfiddle.net/533hc71h/ which were very close in speeds to the point they would flip back and forth.

**TL;DR Question**

Why does `$('#id').find('option').size()` throw a max call stack error on large data,

but `$('#' + id + ' option').size()` does not.

Comment: Probably because the latter allows jQuery to directly leverage the native `document.querySelectorAll(...)` method, while the former forces jQuery to use `.find()`, which will iteratively check the `#id` element for a matching child using some kind of loop. When you have 100k+ elements that will lead to the for loop exceeding the call stack limit. Also, why on earth would you want to render 100k+ nodes in the document? That is highly inefficient and unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: `.size()` is deprecated, you should use `.length`

Comment: Are your users really able to navigate a dropdown menu with hundreds of thousands of items in it?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for letting me know to switch it to length. This code was written before I joined. At that time customers didn't have that many items. And those that do tend to know the name and can do a text search in the box to narrow down the selections. It's on the list as something to improve nonetheless lol.

Comment: And this may be too complex for a comment to answer, but @Terry, forgive my negligence, but why is the native method faster? I'd imagine they would both use a similar method of checking through elements unless one had access to a pre-indexed list of some sort. 
In fact is there a reason for using methods like .find() if there are built in more efficient ones?...

Comment: The native method is built into the browser, it's written in the browser's implementation language (e.g. C or C++), not in JavaScript like jQuery.  It can access the internal DOM structures directly. jQuery tries to take advantage of this when it can, but some cases are hard for it to detect.